# No response from server in my Ionic registration system

Tags: php, ajax, cordova, ionic-framework

I am making a simple registration system in Ionic Cordova. I am sending the data from the form to server through an AJAX call but I am not getting anything in response form the sever. When I made a different conventional form and dent the data to the same script I got the proper response. I am able to figure out the issue. 
form:-

```
<div class="list" id="register">
  <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
      <span class="input-label">Name</span>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="name">
  </label>
  <br>
  <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
      <span class="input-label">Email</span>
      <input type="email" placeholder="Email" id="email">
  </label>
  <br>
  <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
      <span class="input-label">Password</span>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="pass">
  </label><br>
  <button class="button button-full button-assertive" id="signup">
      Submit
  </button>
```

AJAX call:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#signup").click(function(){
    console.log("Button clicked");
var name=$("#name").val();
var email=$("#email").val();
var pass=$("#pass").val();
var dataString="name="+name+"&email="+email+"&pass="+pass+"&signup=";
if($.trim(name).length>0 && $.trim(email).length>0 && $.trim(pass).length>0)
{
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "http://127.0.0.1/ionic/reg.php",
data: {dataString: dataString,signup:true},
success: function(data){
if(data =="success")
{
alert("Thank you for Registering with us! you can login now");
}
else if(data =="exist")
{
alert("Hey! You alreay has account! you can login with us");
}
else if(data =="failed")
{
alert("Something Went wrong");
}
}
});
}
return false;
});

});
```

PHP script:-

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
include 'db_connect.php';
if(isset($_POST['signup']))
{   
    $name=trim($_POST['name']);
    $email=trim($_POST['email']);
    $password=trim($_POST['pass']);
    $login=mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con,"select * from `phonegap_login` where `email`='$email'"));
    if($login!=0)
    {
        echo "exist";
    }
    else
    {
        $q=mysqli_query($con,"insert into `phonegap_login` (`name`,`email`,`password`) values ('$name','$email','$password')");
    if($q)
    {
    echo "success";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "failed";
    }
    }
    echo mysql_error();
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: have you tried `var dataString = $('form').serialize();` ?

Comment: Nope but I had done that in an earlier project

Comment: What happens if you replace ajax data property with `data: dataString` ?

Comment: Nothing I have tried that too

Comment: @TheDrot It worked this time with your solution